# Manually numbering an equation in Beamer

Tags: beamer, numbering

Similar to an old 2011 posting *[here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38716/adding-letters-to-equation-numbers)*, I would like to manually tag a particular line of equation with number in Beamer. I tried using `\tag{}` command but it does not work, putting in `\usepackage{amsmath}` also does not help. I am working under these environments:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\mode {
\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\usecolortheme{beaver}}
```

And here is a compilable example from my slides:

`$x = r \cos \theta \tag{1}$`.

Here, ShareLatex ignores `\tag{1}` but compiles the rest of the equation correctly.

Please advise and thanks for your time.

PS.: I do not have any need to reference the tagged equation later.

Comment: Could you please provide a compilable minimal working example?

Comment: @HerrK. Thanks for your suggestion. See the above for compilable example. Thanks again.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a small correction of (first version of) your code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
1+1=2 \tag{mytag}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The source of your problem seems to be inline formula, i.e. between dollar signs, not inside, say, `equation` environment.

Comment: Thank you! Let me work on it and will get back with you if there is still any issue. Thanks again.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your last comment. Did you say that \tag{ } can not be used between dollar signs? Since I have to use dollar signs, what should I do to manually number an equation? Thanks again.

Comment: @A.Magnus Using `\tag` simply between dollars your should obtain amsmath error `\tag not allowed here`. Your `\tag` should be in a place, where the behaviour is as between double dollars, e.g.  `\[ 2\tag{second}\]`.