# tex4ht gives !Package amsmath Error: \tag not allowed here

Tags: tex4ht

This might be an known limitation in tex4ht, I do not know. But this MWE below gives the error

```
! Package amsmath Error: \tag not allowed here.
```

Only when run with `make4ht`. No error with lualatex nor with pdflatex.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}
\[
x=y \tag{1}
\]
\end{document}
```

The output is

```
>make4ht  foo.tex
.....
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(./foo.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
....
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht))
(./foo.aux)

! Package amsmath Error: \tag not allowed here.

See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                                                                                    
l.7 x=y \tag
            {1}
?
```

List files

```
*File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size11.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 amsmath.sty    2016/11/05 v2.16a AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
```

Version

```
which make4ht
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/scripts/make4ht/make4ht
```

Is the above known issue with make4ht? What should I do to workaround this? Do I need to change `\[..\]` to `\begin{align}....\end{align}` to use `\tag{}` with tex4ht? No error there with make4ht. Only error when using tag with `\[..\]`

Comment: Generally, \\[...\\] used for the unnumbered display equation, may be the error due to that tag, as you suggested, change the same to align environment then check the same...

Comment: @MadyYuvi -- please *not* `align`!  single-line equations should use the `equation` environment.  (the spacing above and below is calculated differently for `equation` and `align`.)

Comment: @MadyYuvi  But for one equation I've always used `\[...\]` and not `align`.  Also there is no error with lualatex nor with pdflatex using `tag` with `\[...\]`. I've also seen `tag` used with     `\[...\]`  by Latex experts. For example  this accepted answer [adding-letters-to-equation-numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38716/adding-letters-to-equation-numbers) uses `tag` with `\[...\]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amsmath rededines `\[` and `\]` to produce `\begin{equation*}` resp. `\end{equation*}`. `tex4ht` redefines it to something different, so the `\tag` doesn't work here anymore. You can try the `amsmath` definitions yourself:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\[}{\begin{equation*}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\]}{\end{equation*}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This is a result:

[image]

Comment: Why don't we update the amsmath.sty in tex4ht to include these `\DeclareRobustCommand`'s?

Comment: @FrankScience I cannot get it to work correctly, it clashes with some options