# Adding equation name along with equation number

Tags: tags, equation-number, eqref

I want to include an additional text (say the equation name), along with the equation number. The equation name is to be displayed only at the place where the equation is displaced, i.e. when I use \eqref, I should only get the equation number.

I tried a few solutions from the forum, but could not find a satisfactory solution. Here's the code that I have so far

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\owntag}[2][\relax]{% \owntag[short label]{tag}
  \ifx#1\relax\relax\def\owntag@name{#2}\else\def\owntag@name{#1}\fi% base label
  \refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation, #2}%
  \expandafter\ltx@label\expandafter{eq:\owntag@name}%
  \edef\@currentlabel{\theequation, #2}\expandafter\ltx@label\expandafter{Eq:\owntag@name}%
  \def\@currentlabel{#2}\expandafter\ltx@label\expandafter{tag:\owntag@name}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_i} = 0 \qquad \mathrm{or} \qquad \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{u} = 0 
    \owntag[example]{Mass conservation}
\end{align}

the mass conservation equation \eqref{mass}.
```

this is the output thus far.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What eventually worked for me is the following:

```
\refstepcounter{equation}\label{eq:mass}
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_i} = 0 \qquad \mathrm{or} \qquad \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{u} = 0 
    \tag{\theequation ,\ Mass\ Conservation}
    \label{dummy}
\end{equation}

This is the mass conservation equation \eqref{eq:mass}. This is its dummy label \eqref{dummy}.
```

gives the output:
[image]

The idea is to correctly step and reference (using \refstepcounter) the equation before it is typeset, and use the equation number in \tag (via \theequation) for appropriate labelling and referencing.

Thanks to Werner's answer in this post! [Adding letters to equation numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38716/adding-letters-to-equation-numbers)